# How to show an Alert Dialog for a background FCM message when notification is pressed

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I would like some help to show an alert dialog when the I press the Firebase push notification shown in the top notification bar on the android device when you swipe downwards from the complete top.

I need it to open the activity and show the alert dialog with the notification message with an OK button after the notification in the notification bar is pressed.

May someone please help me to do so on Android Studio 3.0.1

Comment: can you write your code were you are having problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope so it will be helpful for you

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context,YourActivityClassHere.class);
notifyIntent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//UNIQUE_ID if you expect more than one notification to appear
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SimpleNotification.this, UNIQUE_ID, 
            notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

just make the PendingIntent open up one of your Activities and have your Activity be complete transparent and just open a Dialog.